# headermap cache got stuck?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

In Cakephp 1.3 I have a caching problem: the webroot/img/imagecache/headermap got stuck somehow. I cannot ls or du the contents. The disk device is full and I suspect the headermap being the culprit:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2258 abc www-data     61440 Sep 23 09:40 avatars
drwxrwxrwx    3 abc www-data      4096 Jan 27  2012 gallery
drwxrwxrwx    2 abc www-data 132255744 Sep 25 11:49 headermap
```

Can I just rm -rf headermap? Or is this unwise?

Comment: CakePHP doesn't make use of any such file out of the box, so that is either completely unrelated, or from a plugin or some custom application/server specific code, nothing that anyone here could really help you with, at least not without additional information.

Comment: Thanks ndm. Yes, I suspect it to be a custom build cache. Meanwhile I am rm -rf'ing the thing which takes ages but the "disk use" number is steadily coming down.